# Определение геолокации и выведение результатов на сайте

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Мне для лендинга надо настроить определение геолокации посетителя, чтобы при определении города (например, Владивосток) в заголовке выводилось "Услуги связи в г. Владивосток" (например).
Сам не силен, порыскал в интернете - нашел код Яндекс Карт. Установил - работает через раз. Мне надо что-то сделать с "в г. ", которое остается в заголовке, даже если город не был определен (получается: "Услуги связи в г.").
Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы это "в г." выводилось только в случае, если город был определен? И, соответственно, не выводилось, если город не был определен.

Код такой:

```
            <script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          window.onload = function () {
             if (ymaps.geolocation.city != '') {
                jQuery("#user-city").text(ymaps.geolocation.city);
                jQuery("#user-geo").text('в г. ');
             } else {
                jQuery("#user-city").text('');                     
                jQuery("#user-geo").text('');
                }
            }
        </script>
```

А выводит результаты так:

```
    <h1 class="" style="">Услуги связи<br><span id="user-geo" style=""></span><span id="user-city" style=""></span></h1>
```

в код я сам залез, чую, напортачил)))

Помогите, плиз!

Comment: По условиям использования у вас должна быть карта на странице https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage?from=mapsapi , она у вас есть?

Comment: @se0ga, здравствуйте! Нет, она мне не нужна и я, если честно, не думал об этом. А без карты не будет работать? У меня почему-то определяет город, если заходишь с компа или со смартфона (через wifi), и не определяет, если заходишь со смарта через 3-4g... Это был бы конечно идеальный вариант, если бы скрипт определял всё гео.. Это бы решило проблему в принципе...

Comment: По условиям использования бесплатного апи нельзя использовать определение геолокация если нет карты на странице. Именно на это я обращаю ваше внимание https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage?from=mapsapi

Comment: "И не определяет, если заходишь со смарта через 3-4g..." Попрубуйте апи 2.1 там тоже есть такая проблема? https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation

Comment: @se0ga, спасибо за наводку. Сейчас попробую

Comment: Нет, не получается. Помогите, плиз, кто-нибудь. Я в jquery не силен, мне определение геолокации не так принципиально (город у меня при текущих настройках все равно определяется, правда, кроме смартфонов с мобильным интернетом). Мне главное настроить отображение фразы "в г. " в зависимости от того определился город или нет. Т.е. если город определился - то "в г. " и город отображается (например, "Услуги связи в г. Сочи"), если город не определился - то "в г. " и, соответсвенно, название города не отображается и не портит заголовок (например, "Услуги связи")

Comment: Сейчас если город не определился, то отображается "Услуги связи в г. "

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, если города нет, даже на архивной версии API 2.0 написано только "Услуги связи".
Условие проверки ответа геолокации в этом случае достаточно сократить до **if (ymaps.geolocation.city)**:

```
if (ymaps.geolocation.city) {
    jQuery("#user-city").text(ymaps.geolocation.city);
    jQuery("#user-geo").text('в г. ');
} else {
    jQuery("#user-city").text('');
    jQuery("#user-geo").text('');
}
```

Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/smg61Lfz/

Если же за основу брать актуальную версию API, следует прописать в вызов полученный в [кабинете разработчика](https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/) apikey, а проверку местоположения выполнять с провайдером 'auto' или 'browser', а не только по ip. При наличии ответа получить город сейчас можно строкой

```
geo1 = result.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('metaDataProperty').GeocoderMetaData.Address.Components.pop().name;
```

и уже полученное значение города выводить в **#user-city**

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/weoqx9tk/